# ModelForm For Registration HttpResponseError

Tags: python, django, httpresponse, django-forms

First off, I know what the error means, I'm just confused on the configuration.

I'm getting an error of:

```
views.Registration didn't return an HttpResponse object
```

The issue is when I visit `localhost/Register`, I get the above error.

**Q:** If I want  `localhost/Register` to show form from `RegistrationForm()` when it loads the `register.html` template within `render()` (at the bottom) when `/Register` is accessed. How do I do that? Do I need to create another view like `/NewUser` that I currently have specified? My thought was that `render()` was going to execute to show the `template` (with the form inside it) when viewing `/Register`

Code:
a **view** of:

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPass = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/NewUser/?user=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError('Invalid Request', code='300') ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'form': RegForm 
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should just move everything from the `else` onwards back one indentation level. Otherwise, nothing is returned if the request is not a POST.

Comment: Please provide code to show me what you mean. I would really appreciate it

Comment: Nvm- i got it! Wow, still getting used to the indentation. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to render something if the request is 'GET' instead of 'POST': ie.

```
def Registration(request):
    RegForm = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if RegForm.is_valid():
            clearUserName = RegForm.cleaned_data['userNm']   
            clearPass = RegForm.cleaned_data['userPass']
            RegForm.save()
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/NewUser/?user=' + clearUserName)
            except:
                raise ValidationError('Invalid Request', code='300') ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
        else:
            RegForm = RegistrationForm()

        return render(request, 'VA/reuse/register.html', {
            'form': RegForm 
        })
    else:
        RegForm=RegistrationForm()
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'formset': RegForm})
```

of course, you should change the context for your template, depending on whatever it is you need to render.

Comment: While, this works too, is there any reason to do this, this way - instead of Daniel Roseman's suggestions?

Comment: It depends what you want to do. I often do this so I can pass an `'error': True` context to my template, to change the formatting of the page when an error is present.